# How do I invoke Business Rules from the Node-RED editor in Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules, node-red

I am working with the Node-RED editor on Bluemix, and am trying to execute rules that are deployed to the Business Rules service. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had to bind the app to the Business Rules service instance on Bluemix. Then, in the Node-RED flow editor, I used an http request node, with the following attributes defined with values for the ruleset retrieved from the Details page on the Bluemix console:

```
Method: POST
URL: https://brsv2-12345678.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/MyRuleApp/1.0/myrules/1.0
"Use basic authentication?" checked
Username: resAdmin
Password: <password>
Return: a parsed JSON object
```

Comment: The password would be retrieved from the Connection Settings tab of the Business Rules instance